# Unable to run truffle console

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

When I'm running the truffle compile cmd getting the prompt "Everything is upto date." ABIS folder is created but the corresponding file related to contacts are not there. Basically, the folder is empty. Ganache is running, settings are correct. Please see the attached screenshot for more info. But when I run truffle console it says "unbale to connect to the server." Anyone has any idea what's happening. I'm running windows.[image]

truffke_config.js

```
 networks: {
development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
  port: 7545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
  network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing ganache-CLI via WSL. Able to interact with the local blockchain now.